# Enlist, engage or recruit the help?

Tags: word-choice

> To decorate my room, I .... the help of my roomate.
>
> draft - engage - recruit - **enlist**

Can I use "engage" or "recruit" instead?

Comment: They're all fine, but idiomatically we do tend to ***enlist** [the help of someone or something]*. It's all a matter of opinion though.

Answer (score 1):

Normally we **draft** or **recruit** or **engage** *someone* to help, and  **enlist** the *help* of someone.

But [you will find](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recruit%20the%20help%20of%2Cenlist%20the%20help%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecruit%20the%20help%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenlist%20the%20help%20of%3B%2Cc0) "recruit the help".